# Manipulate struct directly or via return

Tags: go

I noticed that I am not consistent when writing golang regarding the following question: Is it better to manipulate a struct in its methods via the struct itself directly or by using return? Since this question sounds stupid, here's an example:

### Manipulate a struct directly

http://play.golang.org/p/7G5D8Pm5wv

### Via return

http://play.golang.org/p/L9Z_t7pA8b

Please explain why one attempt is better than the other. An if both somehow wrong, please give an example that would be ok.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on how you use your struct. If you use it as an object i.e. there function with receivers of that type I think you should manipulate the state (the fields of the struct) with functions too. If you use the struct purely as a data store, then manipulating the fields directly seems more OK.

Read

Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship by Robert C. Martin, chapter 6 on Objects & Data structures

Google for that book and you will find online versions.

and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter